# How to select some properties in JSON

Tags: json

Here is the data:

```
var data1 = [{
"Date": "2016-07-09",
"H1_PNL2": 20, 
"H1_NAV2" : 20
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
"H2_NAV2" : 20,
"NAV": 26.28,
"PNL": 7.61
}, {
"Date": "2016-07-10",
"H1_PNL2": 20, 
"H1_NAV2" : 20
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
"H2_NAV2" : 20,
"NAV": 27.55,
"PNL": 12.89
}];
```

If I only want to select `Date` and `H2_PNL2` i.e

```
var data1 = [{
"Date": "2016-07-09",
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
}, {
"Date": "2016-07-10",
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
}];
```

How to select the specific properties I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate through your array, then for each object construct a new object with just the properties that interest you:

```
data1.map(o => ({ Date: o.Date, H2_PNL2: o.H2_PNL2 }));
```

EDIT: Deleting properties can go two ways, depending on if you want to preserve the original or not.

Destructive:

```
data1.forEach(o => { delete o.NAV; delete o.PNL; });
```

Non-destructive:

```
data1.map(o => {
  var c = Object.assign({}, o);
  delete c.NAV; delete c.PNL;
  return c;
});
```

Comment: by the way if I just want to delete `NAV` and `PNL` how to do?